# When would this linear system have no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Given this linear system for  $x,y,z \in \mathbb{R}$

\begin{aligned}
    (a+1)x + ay - az = 2+a  \\ 
   (a+1)x + (a+2)y - (a + 2)z = a+4 \\
   (a+1)x+ ay +(a^2-6)z = a^2 - 2a + 4 \\
   (2a+2)x+ 2ay +(a^2 - a - 6)z = a^2 - a + 6 \\
\end{aligned}
For what values of $a$ does the system have one solution? infinite solutions? no solutions?

I proceed by putting its associated augmented matrix in row reduced echelon form and get that $x = \frac{2}{a+1}$, $y = 1 + \frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{(a+3)(a-2)}$ and $z = \frac{(a-1)(a-2)}{(a+3)(a-2)}$. I understand that if $a = -3 $ or $a = -1$ that the system will have no solutions. however I am confused about $a = 2$. If i plug in a = 2 into the original system and try to row reduce from there, I get infinite solutions. If i plug $a = 2$ into my solutions for $x,y,z$ and cancel out the $(a-2)$ terms, and plug these back into the original system, they seem to work out perfectly. So whats going on with $a = 2$? I haven't found anything in my book about how to deal with this. Am I allowed to cancel out the $\frac{a-2}{a-2}$ in my solutions for $z$ and $y$? Any help in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: Check your calculations leading up to your three formulas and see if you accidentally divided by zero along the way (when $a=2$).

Comment: @Lovsovs I only divided by $(a + 1), (a - 2),(a + 3)$ to get my solutions of $x,y, z$. For the system when $a = 2$, it happens that $R_1 = R_3 = \frac{1}{2}R_4$

Comment: So if you divided by (a-2), and you're trying the value a = 2, then you divided by ...

Comment: @ConMan. I divided $(a-1)(a-2)$ by $(a-2)(a+3)$, so the $a-2$ terms cancel out. However I don't know what that tells me about if $a=2$. If i didn't cancel them out, I would have $\frac{0}{0}$.

Comment: The thing is that you can't perform an operation where you divide by zero, so anything you got as a result of that operation isn't true.